# How to aggregate with join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new to SQL and I was wondering if someone could help me find the quantity on hand (dqty-sqty) for each iname? This is what I've been trying to do so far but the total quantity that I get is wrong:

```
select delivery.iname, sum(dqty-sqty) as "Quantity on Hand"    
from sale join delivery on    
sale.iname=delivery.iname    
group by delivery.iname    
order by delivery.iname;
```

Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to take the sum of the delivered and sold items individually as `JOINs` will not work directly on tables as there is `many to many relationship` between two tables.

Try this:

```
SELECT D.INAME, DQTY - SQTY AS "Quantity on Hand"
FROM
(SELECT DELIVERY.INAME, SUM(DQTY) DQTY
FROM DELIVERY
GROUP BY DELIVERY.INAME) D
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SALE.INAME, SUM(SQTY) SQTY
FROM SALE
GROUP BY SALE.INAME) S
ON D.INAME = S.INAME;
```

I have used `LEFT JOIN` in case the item is not sold.

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.